# Unable to find ^M when reading file

Tags: vim

I am using a linux OS and attempting to find the ^M characters in a .vim file, specifically jcommenter.vim. I would like to find and replace the ^M characters but am unable to do so. I have tried

**%s/^V^M//g**

and

**%s/\r/\r/g**

Unfortunately neither are able to find ^M. I have read that when vim reads a file, it will not include ^M, is this true? How can I find and get rid of ^M?

Edit:
This is a sample of the error I recieve:

```
line   21:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
line   31:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
```

This occurs everywhere there is a blank line.

EDIT:!!!
I have found a clue!

**/usr/share/vim/macros/jcommenter.vim"[converted][dos]**

dos?????? How do I destroy [converted][dos]?

Comment: Maybe your file doesn't contain any ^M characters?

Comment: `^M` is inputted by typing ctrl-V ctrl+M. Are you doing that, or typing the literal characters `"^M"`?

Comment: Yes, I tried "^M" and ctrl-V ctrl-M

Comment: Look into `:help fileformat`, this will handle line-ending conversions for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your file from "dos" format to "unix" format, load the file in vim and do:

```
:set ff=unix
:w
:q
```

The `ff` is short for `fileformat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
$ dos2unix plugin/jcommenter.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromdos file`  (in command line, not in vim). This usually gets rid of odd control characters.

If you don't have it you can get it from the standard repos